# Create SQL table across mutltiple tables using Inner join

Tags: mysql

Tables (I have also added the key fields of each table):

**-tblproperty**:
propertyid, address

**-tblpropertyassetclass**:
propertyassetclassid

**-tblpropertyassetclass_property_mapping**:
propertyassetclassid, propertyid

**-tblcompdetails**:
mlsnumber, approved_comps

**-tblmls_add_derived**:
mlsnumber, propertyaddress

Goal: Is to find for all addresses in a particular propertyassetclassid in tblpropertyassetclass, what its approved_comps value is.

```
SELECT address 
FROM   properties.tblpropertyassetclass_property_mapping a 
       INNER JOIN properties.tblproperty b 
               ON a.propertyid = b.propertyid 
WHERE  propertyassetclassid = 3
```

This query that I created gets the all the address for a given propertyassetclassid(in this case 3). The only way I can get to approved_comps is if I have the mlsnumber which I don't. So somehow I need to match the address that I have with address in tblmls_add_dervived to get the mlsnumber. Then use that mlsnumber to get approved_comps.

Could someone please help me. I have no idea how to get this to happen.

So let us say that the query above gave back 2 address
25 Poppy Street
1234 Apple Street
for each address I want to know its approved_comps value

```
SELECT approved_comps
FROM properties.tblcompdetails a
       INNER JOIN properties.tblmls_add_derived b 
            ON a.mlsnumber = b.mlsnumber  
WHERE propertyaddress LIKE '%707 Country Aire%'
```

I was able to create this query, but this is for a specific one. How can I join both of the queries together?

Comment: `Mysql` <> `Sql Server`!!! So please choose the one you are using.

Comment: @Fireblade am trying to do this in Mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 additional inner joins are necessary to connect the `tblcompdetails` and `tblmls_add_derived` to the query.  Note: The use of aliases to explicitly define each column we are using in our query. Without explicitly defining which column comes from which table, the ambiguous column error message would be displayed.

```
SELECT b.address, d.approved_comps
FROM   properties.tblpropertyassetclass_property_mapping a 
       INNER JOIN properties.tblproperty b 
               ON a.propertyid = b.propertyid 
       INNER JOIN properties.tblmls_add_derived c
               ON b.address = c.propertyaddress
       INNER JOIN properties.tblcompdetails d
               ON c.mlsnumber = d.mlsnumber
WHERE  a.propertyassetclassid = 3
```